# Chrome Postman missing wildfire headers (fire php)

Tags: google-chrome, postman, firephp

I use FirePHP and FirePHP4Chrome to debug my applications, unfortunately in postman i don't see any Wildfire headars sent back along my responses. Is it possible to enable these headers and somehow use FirePHP4CHrome extension in the Postman to display messages on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem!

You need to manipulate the header of the request,

```
x-firephp-version:0.0.6
```

Then you get the messages.